# Javascript passing arrays between nested Functions()

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, function, return-value

I keep getting undefined in the alertbox popup...am I missing something? And there is data on `nodeArray[0]`, because if I put it inside the for loop it alerts correctly.

```
function grabNodes(env, poolName){
    var env = "dev";
    var nodeArray = new Array();

    var ajaxRequest; //initialize ajax object

    var browser = navigator.appName; //find the browser name
    if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        /* Create the object using MSIE's method */
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else{
        /* Create the object using other browser's method */
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        // Get the data from the server's response
        //what on this page is changing
            var xmlRes=ajaxRequest.responseXML.documentElement;
            try {
                for(var i=0; i<xmlRes.getElementsByTagName('node').length;i++){
                    nodeArray[i] = xmlRes.getElementsByTagName('node')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
                }//end for loop
            }
            catch (err){
            }
             alert(nodeArray[0]);
        }

    }

//return nodeArray;
}
```

function is called by:

```
function other(){
    oNodeArray = grabNodes(env, poolName);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax calls are *asynchronous*. `alert(nodeArray[0]);` is executed **before** the function you assigned to `ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange`.

Put the `alert` in the callback and it will work (provided you get a valid response). **Every code that has to operate on the result has to be called from the callback.**

**Update:** You cannot return data. You have to restructure your code to use callbacks.

If your current code is like

```
oNodeArray = grabNodes(env, poolName);

// work on `oNodearray`
```

you have to change it to:

```
grabNodes(env, poolName, function(oNodearray) {
     // work on `oNodearray`
});
```

and the Ajax callback has to call the function you pass and pass the array to it:

```
function grabNodes(env, poolName, callback){
    //....
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        // stuff
        callback(nodeArray);
    }
}
```

Because Ajax calls are asynchronous, they don't block the execution of the code. You need to pass a function that will be executed once the data is received.

---

**Further comments:**

- Use `var nodeArray = [];` to initialise an array.
- `var env = "dev";` will shadow the parameter `env`. If you want to assign a default value, do

  ```
  env = env || 'dev';
  ```

Comment: so the i moved the alert and it gives me the data so I know it is working. But I am not understanding the return statement...if I put it there where does it return to? I need it to return to the oNodeArray which is in another function that calls grabNodes()

Comment: @Jim: You don't need to put a return statement in the callback, it will have no effect. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: grabNodes() has already returned by the time you set the array in the ajax callback.  You need to re-formulate your code such that you can call a given function with nodeArray as a parameter from your ajax callback.  You're trying to program this in a synchronous manner but ajax is by definition not synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call is most likely not yet complete when the alert is invoked. This should be placed inside the onreadystatechange handler.